# JAX-RS Response not as expected

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am trying actually to extend the REST API of an open source project (logicaldoc) to allow one more setting to be updated.

```
@Override
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@ApiOperation(value = "Uploads a document", notes = "Creates or updates an existing document, if used in update mode docId must be provided, when used in create mode folderId is required. Returns the ID of the created/updated document. &lt;br/&gt;Example: curl -u admin:admin -H ''Accept: application/json'' -X POST -F folderId=4 -F filename=newDoc.txt -F filedata=@newDoc.txt http://localhost:8080/services/rest/document/upload")
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "docId", value = "The ID of an existing document to update", required = false, dataType = "integer", paramType = "form"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "folderId", value = "Folder ID where to place the document", required = false, dataType = "string", paramType = "form"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "release", value = "Indicates whether to create or not a new major release of an updated document", required = false, dataType = "string", paramType = "form", allowableValues = "true, false"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "filename", value = "File name", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "form"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "language", value = "Language of the document (ISO 639-2)", required = false, dataType = "string", paramType = "form", defaultValue = "en"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "filedata", value = "File data", required = true, dataType = "file", paramType = "form") })
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Authentication failed"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Generic error, see the response message") })
public Response upload(@ApiParam(hidden = true) List<Attachment> attachments) throws Exception {
    String sid = validateSession();
    try {
        Long docId = null;
        Long folderId = null;
        boolean release = false;
        String filename = null;
        String language = null;
        DataHandler datah = null;

        for (Attachment att : attachments) {
            Map<String, String> params = att.getContentDisposition().getParameters();
            // log.debug("keys: {}", params.keySet());
            // log.debug("name: {}", params.get("name"));

            if ("docId".equals(params.get("name"))) {
                docId = Long.parseLong(att.getObject(String.class));
            } else if ("folderId".equals(params.get("name"))) {
                folderId = Long.parseLong(att.getObject(String.class));
            } else if ("release".equals(params.get("name"))) {
                release = Boolean.parseBoolean(att.getObject(String.class));
            } else if ("filename".equals(params.get("name"))) {
                filename = att.getObject(String.class);
            } else if ("language".equals(params.get("name"))) {
                language = att.getObject(String.class);
            } else if ("filedata".equals(params.get("name"))) {
                datah = att.getDataHandler();
            }
        }

        long documentId = super.upload(sid, docId, folderId, release, filename, language, datah);

        return Response.ok("" + documentId).build();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        log.error(t.getMessage(), t);
        return Response.status(500).entity(t.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

When I installed a binary distribution of logicaldoc I could use the REST endpoint.

Now when I downloaded the sources and build it from the sources my response always contains this:

javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(ILjava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$ResponseBuilder;

Normally it should contain the new documentId as string.

When debugging in eclipse the documentId in the java code contains the new documentId as long value (e.g. 119).

Can someone give me some hints whats going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

In a C# console application the interesting part looks like this

```
            var contents = result.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine("created documentID: " + contents);
```

contents contained the documentId before. Now it is returning that object description string.

On request: This is the complete console application code used to upload all my scanned documents.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using LogicalDocHotFolder.Util;

using LogicalDocHotFolder.Models;
using System.Data;

using Z.EntityFramework.Plus;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LogicalDocHotFolder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            long? importAttributeTemplateId = null;
            long tmp;

            if (Int64.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogicalDocAttributeTemplateId"], out tmp)) {
                importAttributeTemplateId = tmp;
            }

            long importFolderId = Int64.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogicalDocImportToFolder"]);

            string baseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogicalDocCaseURL"];
            string logicalDocUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogicalDocUser"];
            string logicalDocPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogicalDocPassword"];

            string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogicalDocImportFromFolder"];
            string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImportFromFolderUser"]; 
            string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImportFromFolderPassword"]; 

            FileInfo[] files = GetFileInfos(path, username, password);

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);

            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(logicalDocUser + ":" + logicalDocPassword);
            var header = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = header;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/plain");//ACCEPT header
            // That is important for LD 7.7.2 and LD 7.7.3 (unlessy you apply the patch BasicAuthenticationFilter)
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "C# service");//User-Agent header



            foreach (FileInfo fi in files.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTimeUtc))
            {
                var contentmp = new MultipartFormDataContent();

                contentmp.Add(new StringContent(String.Format("{0}", importFolderId)), "folderId");
                contentmp.Add(new StringContent("de"), "language");

                FileStream fstream;

                try
                {
                    fstream = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                } catch
                {
                    continue;
                }


                contentmp.Add(new StringContent(fi.Name), "filename");
                //contentmp.Add(new StringContent(fi.CreationTimeUtc.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")), "date");

                contentmp.Add(new StreamContent(fstream), "filedata", fi.Name);

                var result = client.PostAsync("/test/services/rest/document/upload", contentmp);
                Console.WriteLine(result.Result.ToString());


                var contents = result.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine("created documentID: " + contents);

                long newId = Convert.ToInt64(contents);

                fstream.Close();

                using (LogicalDoc81HotFolderEntities ctx = new LogicalDoc81HotFolderEntities())
                {
                    hf_importinfo info = new hf_importinfo();
                    ctx.hf_importinfo.Add(info);

                    info.ld_Id = newId;
                    info.file_date = fi.CreationTimeUtc;
                    info.file_name = fi.Name;
                    info.import_folder = importFolderId;
                    info.last_modified = fi.LastWriteTimeUtc;
                    info.origin_path = fi.FullName;

                    ctx.SaveChanges();

                }

            }
        }



        private static FileInfo[] GetFileInfos(string path, string username, string password)
        {

            using (UNCAccessWithCredentials network = new UNCAccessWithCredentials())
            {

                network.NetUseWithCredentials(path, username, null, password);

                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

                return di.GetFiles();


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are most likely calling toString() on the object?  Please show the code used to print the response.

Comment: I use Postman. But the reponse size shows 267 byte at all. 112 body and 155 in the headers. The epxected response should have about 5 bytes.

Comment: Beside that I used a C# console application that was able to upload the files in the binary distribution.but not anymore with my source compilation.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your C# code, including the definition of the result object.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in JAX-RS there will be some provider which will do POJO <-> JSON conversion automatically.

In your case, it is possible that toString() is being done, either by you or by default because the JSON mapper is missing.

I generally use Jersey implementation JAX-RS. Jersey can use Jackson to enable automatic conversion.

You can take a look at this tutorial for more information:
https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/

The Maven dependencies have to be right and the POJO mapping feature should be enabled (in web.xml).

Note: 
It can be hard to debug because it is declaratively added. 
But, if the feature is  enabled and still the classes are missing I would expect it to throw some exception.

Comment: That seems to be a good start point for searching. But assumed that the JSON mapper is not working. Shouldn't it return at least the string representation of the value instead of the description of the object? In my case... shouldn't it return "113" as documentId instead of "javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.status(ILjava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$ResponseBuilder;" Especially the semicolon at the end is weird in my opinion.

Comment: Response.ok("" + documentId).build(); gives a response/status object. And that probably has not implemented a toString(). So, it prints class name and something like hash code.

Comment: Funny thing is I compiled multiple times for different changes. Normally I got this result. Suddenly without having something changed at a relevant place I got the correct result (the document id). Then after next compile I got the object description text again. Seems to be a kind of edge case. Someone else had the same here: https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail-poc/issues/16

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I needed to downgrade the javax package to version 2.0.1 and now it's working again.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```